# Tablet's scaling my web page by 1.5x causing layout issues

Tags: html, css, tablet

So I have a web app that looks perfectly fine at 1024x768 pixels on a laptop (I really don't care about phone at the moment).  However, when I take the same app onto a tablet it doesn't fit even though the pixel availability is way higher than 1024x768.  It turns out that the tablets are scaling my app so it uses a 1.5 x css pixel multiplier causing it to be much larger on the tablets.

I have the following in my html head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

But it still scales the web page.  This code seems to me that it would set the initial scale to 1.0 so that css pixels == hardware pixels, but it doesn't.  I'm not really in a place to use full responsive design for this.  I just need to have tablets stop scaling my values for me.  How can I get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you might be looking for

```
body * {-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
```

read here for the documentations 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust

Comment: This really doesn't sound like an option given how experimental it is and "This property only has an effect on smartphones."  Ok I don't care about phones.  "...As there is no inflation algorithm on desktop browsers, and on some tablet browsers like the iPad, the property is not supported there (and ignored)." Sounds like this doesn't work on tablets much either.

Comment: why don't you try this? its experimental but WORKS, and widely used in HTML email styling.

Comment: @chubbsondubs also `As there is no inflation algorithm on desktop browsers, and on some tablet browsers like the iPad` means no scaling to begin with so it will be ignored IF and ONLY IF you want it to scale otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You're falling victim to the CSS pixel ratio: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density of your device. Each device has a scaling factor applied to css. For example, the ipad mini is a ratio of 2.

There are ways to query the ratio in CSS, but it is not recommended according to Mozilla.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-device-pixel-ratio

```
 @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), /* Webkit-based browsers */
   (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),    /* Older Firefox browsers (prior to Firefox 16) */
   (min-resolution: 2dppx),             /* The standard way */
   (min-resolution: 192dpi)             /* dppx fallback */
```

Comment: Ok so what I can I do to control it?

Comment: Not much, other than add some conditionals that are pretty browser specific to the CSS.